# 405 Error when trying to send email via route with Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Trying to send an email using Laravel but keep getting a 405 error and the whoops page showing:

```
 * @param  array  $others
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

The code is:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/newemail')) }}
  // form items
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And the route is:

```
Route::get('admin/newemail', function()
{
    $email = 'email@hotmail.com';
    $data = array('s' => Input::get('email-heading'));
    Mail::send('emails.wereback', $data, function($message) use ($email){
        // $message details
    });
});
```

However, if I directly go to the url admin/newemail it works fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `Form` helper will generate a html form that uses the POST method. You can specify the method if you need to use a different one:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/newemail', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
```

Or you could also change your route to match POST requests:

```
Route::post('admin/newemail', function()
{
    // [...]
});
```

Comment: I would choose the latter so that one would not accidentally visit `example.com/admin/newemail` and fire an email.

Comment: Ah yes! My logic in my head wasn't thinking properly about this. Post is what I needed not get... :)